# Deprecated: preg_match(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($subject) of type string is deprecated

Tags: php, wamp

I have installed WAMP Server 3.3.0 in my computer and after that when I go to localhost loading page displaying following error messages

> Deprecated: preg_match(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($subject) of type string is deprecated in C:\wamp64\scripts\config.inc.php on line 82

this is my config.inc.php

```
foreach($Text_Encoding as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('~^'.$key.'\s+:\s+(.+)~mi',$output,$matches) === 1) { //line 82
        $Text_Encoding[$key] = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

how could I fix this problem?

Comment: Give $output some value.

Comment: @shingo could you give me some example?

Comment: In your `if`-statement, you can do: `if (is_string($output) && preg_match(....)) { ... }`. That will only call `preg_match()` if `$output` is a string and skip it if it's not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look like you need to change by this ?

```
foreach($Text_Encoding as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('~^'.$key.'\s+:\s+(.+)~mi', $value, $matches) === 1) { 
        $Text_Encoding[$key] = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

Your $output is not set and you don't use $value in your code

Answer (score 1):

The intent of your code fragment likely follows along these lines which is to fetch the current environment encoding and replace the array entries with actual values:

```
$Text_Encoding = array(
    'IsSingleByte' => '',
    'BodyName' => '',
    'EncodingName' => '',
    'HeaderName' => '',
    'WebName' => '',
    'WindowsCodePage' => '',
    'CodePage' => '',
);
$command = 'CMD /D /C powershell [System.Text.Encoding]:: Default';
$output = `$command`;
foreach($Text_Encoding as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('~^'.$key.'\s+:\s+([a-zA-Z0-9\-\'\.\(\) ]+)~mi',$output,$matches) === 1) {
        $Text_Encoding[$key] = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

From this it appears that using `$value` is not what you want.

Source: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,163848,163848